# Representation of indeterminate forms?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I am learning about l'Hospitals rule (side note - interesting history behind it in that it should really be called Bernoulli's rule) and indeterminate forms such as $\frac{0}{0}$ , $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, $\infty - \infty$ etc. Now of course we cannot when writing mathematics explicitly say $\frac{0}{\infty}$ as $\infty$ is not a number but a concept. I would like to know then if there is a standard way to write down an indeterminate *form*. For example

Given $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a} p(x) = \infty$

We can't write that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{p(x)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Is there a way for me to write that that limit is equal to the *form* of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, with an indeterminate form, we discourage the use of the equals sign in "$=\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" and state that it is "of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok, so it is perfectly acceptable to say something like "is of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty} \therefore$ indeterminate ". I find it interesting that when evaluating a limit such that it tends to infinity we do say = $\infty$, despite the fact that it is not really 'equal' to infinity. fascinating. Thanks for your response to my question.

Comment: When we write "$=\infty$", this is shorthand for "the limit does not exist and the way that it doesn't exist is that it grows without bound."  If one uses the two-point compactification of the real line, then $\infty$ becomes a point and it is possible to say $=\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our teachers at university strictly forbade us to write $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$because $\infty$ is not a value. Even though everybody knows what is meant by expressing it that way we were taught to write $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \to \infty$ for $ x\to a$. When using L'Hospital, we were exceptionally allowed to say "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" as long as that was not our final result.